# Is there a way to tell whether a project references another project from the solution or just its binary?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I created three projects as follows:

1. ConsoleApp (Console Application)
2. ProjectReference (Class Library)
3. BinaryReference (Class Library)

To each of the class libraries mentioned above, I added a class as follows:

**ProjectReference**

```
namespace ProjectReference
{
  public class Class1
  {
    public string Property1 = "Property 1 from project reference.";
  }
}
```

**BinaryReference**

```
namespace BinaryReference
{
  public class Class1
  {
    public string Property1 = "Property 1 from binary reference.";
  }
}
```

Then, in the ConsoleApp project, I clicked **Add Reference** and selected the **ProjectReference** class library project from the **Solution -> Project** tab.

Then I clicked **Add Reference** in the ConsoleApp project again, and this time from the **Browse** tab, I selected the binary for the **BinaryReference** class library project.

Next, I build the solution. I expanded the **References** node for **ConsoleApp** to look at the properties of both my references and they appeared *exactly* the same. Had it not been for the way I named them, I couldn't have told which one was a project reference and which one a binary.

**QUESTIONS**

That made me wonder about these two things:

1. Is there a way to tell one from the other?
2. Is it even important if both the reference targets are within the same solution? They'll all build in the right order anyway when you build the solution in Visual Studio.

Even if I had wanted a custom build sequence and wanted to have an MS Build script for this rather than having Visual Studio build it, it would still make no difference as both the projects referenced would have to be built first as they are dependencies for the **ConsoleApp** project?

4. Is one better than the other? I used to hold that the project reference is better but right now, I am challenging little beliefs I have held by critically examining them this way.
5. Things probably would have been different if the **BinaryReference** were not a project in the solution but a project in another solution (but not something I never had the source for because then that is not a moot point; we have that with every Microsoft or third-party assembly we reference)? In that case, it would require me to open that *other* solution which had **BinaryReference** as a project reference and build that before going back to building *this* solution where **BinaryReference** was a binary reference.

Even though I've been programming for years, the reason I am bringing all these questions up is because I am looking at a large enterprise project with a gazillion projects in the solution and some of the references are suspiciously binary ones and not project ones. The tricky part is: the project names do not have the same names as the assemblies they produce.

Comment: So... why do you care that some are references and others binaries in the large project?

Comment: Referencing loose DLLs is a thing of the past. Wrap them up in NuGet packages and deploy to a NuGet server, so that you can manage version dependencies. If it's in the same solution, then it's okay to do a project reference.

Comment: Related [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4358): "Visual Studio 2015 no longer uses a binary reference to a library when its project is loaded in the same solution "

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you. I forgot to mention that for this particular machine, I am using VS 2013 but thank you. That is a very relevant article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference can be told by inspecting the `*.csproj` file of the specific project, which is an Xml file. Binary references use a `Reference` node which looks as follows.

```
<Reference Include="{some info}">
    <SpecificVersion>{some value}</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>{some path}</HintPath>
    <Private>{some value}</Private>
</Reference>
```

Project reference use a `ProjectReference` node which looks as follows.

```
<ProjectReference Include="{some path}">
    <Project>{some guid}</Project>
    <Name>{some name}</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Comment: Not directly related, but I wasted some time until I found out not that not every feature of MSBuild is accessible in the Visual Studio IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you load reference from project or from binary, they all loaded by the file path. It will not make any different whether it is loaded from a project or binary other than when a solution is built, you know that the dependent assemblies also built at the time.

I worked on a enterprise project (50 or more solutions and over 200 projects), the way it was setup is to have a internal nugget server and put latest build of each project on this server. So when another project reference to an assembly, it looks at this local nugget server and get the latest assembly file available when needed.